# How come boolean value is logged as a checkbox is undefined when logged?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to log the value of the check variable which is column 11 it is a checkbox and should come up as true or false if it is ticked or not ticked. However I get a log saying that the value is undefined and I'm not quite so sure as to why this is.

could someone please help? I have put a comment for your reference.

```
function sendEmail() {

 //setup function
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";
 for (i in AllValues) {

 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[13];


//problem here
   var check = CurrentRow[11];
   Logger.log(check)




 if (EmailSent == "sent") 
     continue;

 //set HTML template for information
  message +=
      "<p><b>Timestamp by: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Requester Email: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Star Rating: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Request Category: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Description: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Label: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Ticket ID: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Comment: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p><br><br>";

  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 13).setValue("sent");
}

 var SendTo = "email@email.org.au" + "," + "email@email.org.au";

 var Subject = "CT IT feedback";


  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
}
```

Comment: Are you getting all the other values and just not the checkbox? Are you thinking about both columns and rows to ensure you are targeting the correct value?

Comment: Yeah, all the other values are coming up as undefined, I have made sure both column and rows to ensure this as I have checked each column leading up to this one to

Comment: You are going to need to look at using a nested for loop. Start a1, step through to a-whatever. Once done, step down a row. Will create a basic 2d array example for you below to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you are going to need to think about looping with nested for loop if you are getting values from a sheet.
I am not familiar with those functions you are using in your snippet, but for learning, I have included an example of how to step through a sheet below.

See example below.

```js
var sheet = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12]
];

// Think of the above array as your sheet.
// You will step go 1, 2, 3, 4 and then step down a row
// to 5, 6, 7, 8 and so on.

var rows = sheet.length;
var rowCount;

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    rowCount = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < sheet[i].length; j++) {
        rowCount += sheet[i][j];
    }
    // Finished calculating the row.
    console.log(rowCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is used for iterating over the properties of an object, not for arrays. I'd recommend using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead. So try changing this:

```
 for (i in AllValues) {

   var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

   // Rest of code in loop

}
```

For this:

```
AllValues.forEach(function(CurrentRow) {

  // Rest of code in loop

})
```

Apart from this, `CurrentRow` only goes till index 10, so it cannot access `CurrentRow[11]` and `CurrentRow[13]`. So, when you are defining `WholeRange`, you should take at least 14 columns:

```
var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow, 1, RowRange, 14);
```

Hope this is useful for you!